# Distance between 2 gps points

Tags: php, gps, distance

I am using this function, but I need more accuracy. Any ideas?

```
function distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $miles = true)
{
    $pi80 = M_PI / 180;
    $lat1 *= $pi80;
    $lng1 *= $pi80;
    $lat2 *= $pi80;
    $lng2 *= $pi80;
    $r = 6372.797; // mean radius of Earth in km
    $dlat = $lat2 - $lat1;
    $dlng = $lng2 - $lng1;
    $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * sin($dlng / 2) * sin($dlng / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    $km = $r * $c;
    return ($miles ? ($km * 0.621371192) : $km);
}
```

Comment: Can you define accuracy? With roads, height, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is very acurate, it looks like the haversine formula.
Most probably, your input data is the problem.